# Margin Help Again

Tags: html, css, background, margin

My apologies on the previous question!! I'm very new to stackoverflow and have no idea how to use this as I'm very new to HTML and CSS stuff. I'm taking my first class on it for beginners and we had an example and I'm supposed to replicate it as my project. Please let me know if I'm not doing this right, but here is what my code looks like so far...
I would still like the corners to be rounded, the page to extend on it's own, with the footer always at the bottom. outside of the white.

http://jsfiddle.net/xnu0n3o2/

```
<div id="header">
<h1>H E A D E R</h1>
</div>

<h1>My first project!</h1>
    <p>blah blah blah blah  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  blah blah blah blah</p
<div id="footer">
This is my test footer. I want it to go outside the white area.. To be specific, I want it on the pink below the white. The problem is, when I set the body height to a certain percent, the page doesn't extend on it's own. 
</div>

h1 {
color:purple;
text-align:center;
}

html {background-color:pink;
background-attachment:fixed;
}

body {
background-color:white;
border-radius:20px;
margin-right: 245px;
margin-left: 240px;
margin-top: 100px;
}

#header {
background-color:#6F5997;
border-top-right-radius:15px;
border-top-left-radius:15px;
padding:50px;
}
```

Comment: header and footer tags for a start

Comment: I had them but removed them... :S

Comment: i'm not even sure, teacher told me to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html,
      body {height: 100%; background-color: pink}
      body {padding: 40px 40px 0 40px; box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0}
      p {margin-top: 0}
      .container {height: 100%}

      .header {background-color: #6F5997; height: 20%; border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0}
        h1 {color: purple; margin: 0}

      .body {background-color: #fff; height: 60%; border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px}
        .body h2 {color: purple; margin-top: 0}

      .footer {height: 20%}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <h2>My first project!</h2>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>Blah footer</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above piece of code dynamically changes the height of the individual sections as well. Here is a fiddle of it I just made (http://jsfiddle.net/pavkr/mdfqgfqn/), you could play around with it and see if you can come up with a solution you want.